# how to upload image file via php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, file, file-upload

```
<?php 
$msg='';
//if upload button is pressed
//if (isset($_POST['upload'])){
    if (isset($_POST['Image']['name'])&& isset ($_POST['Upload'])){
        //if (isset($_POST['Image'])){



    //the path to store the uploaded image
    $target = "tutorme5/tutorme/img/".basename($_FILES['Image']['name']);

    //get all the submitted data from the form
    $image = $_FILES['Image']['name'];
    //$image = $_POST['Image']['name'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO User (Image) VALUES ('$image') where UserID='$userID'";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql); // stores submitted data in database

    // now we will move uploaded image into the folder: images/

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Image']['$tmp_name'], $target )) {

        $msg =" Image uploaded successfully";
        print_r($_FILES);


    }else{


        $msg ="there was a problemo uploading image";   



    }



}
?>
```

//retrieving code from db

```
$thing="";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM User";
$result = mysqli_query ($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $thing.= "<img src ='".$row['Image']."' >" ;


}

?>
```

//html and form portion of code

```
<div id="content">
                        <form method="post" action="profile.php" enctype="mulitipart/form-data" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
                            <div>
                            <input type="file" name="Image">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <input type ="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <?php echo $thing; ?>
                            </div>
                            </form>
                            </div>`enter code here`
```

> I have no idea why this won't work. I have watched countless video
>   tutorials and have been puzzled by this for two days now. Any help would be
>   much appreciated

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: At first it was say " undefined index Image"

Comment: if (isset($_POST['upload'])){

Comment: when I was just using the above line, but now I don't get any sort of error when I use   " if (isset($_POST['Image']['name'])&& isset ($_POST['Upload'])){  " I just doesn't work

Comment: you can debug what is being sent by using xdebug or just doing `var_dump($_POST)` or `var_dump($_FILES)`

Answer (score 0):

Change $_POST to $_FILES

```
    if (isset($_FILES['Image']['name'])&& isset ($_POST['Upload'])){
        //if (isset($_POST['Image']))
```

Also change `$tmp_name` to `tmp_name`  here

```
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'], $target )) {
```

And be sure about image path, it should contain path `"tutorme5/tutorme/img/"`

```
    $thing.= "<img src ='".$row['Image']."' >" ;
```

Comment: http://localhost:9080/tutorme5/tutorme/profile.php and there is an img folder. Would that make this path correct? "tutorme5/tutorme/img/"

Comment: `CREATE TABLE User
(
UserID varchar(8) NOT NULL,
Password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Email varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Phone varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Major varchar(30) NOT NULL,
School varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Status varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Image varchar(200),
PRIMARY KEY(UserID)
);`

Comment: Wasn't sure if it was a problem that I have Image stored as a varchar instead of blob in the db.

Comment: Is images storing in img folder

Comment: no, they are not. C:\wamp64\www\tutorme5\tutorme\img

Comment: what you get `echo $target = "tutorme5/tutorme/img/".basename($_FILES['Image']['name']);` here

Comment: `) Notice: Undefined index: Image in C:\wamp64\www\tutorme5\tutorme\profile.php on line 265`